# Unknown object in Python and Boolean operation

Tags: python, operator-overloading, logical-operators

Consider this `Unknown` class:

```
class Unknown:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self

unknown = Unknown()
assert (unknown + 1) is unknown
assert (1 + unknown) is unknown
```

This also works for `__mul__`, `__rmul__`, etc.

However, for Boolean operators e.g.:

```
assert (unknown or True) is True
assert (unknown or False) is unknown
```

Attempts such as -

```
def __or__(self, other):
    return self if not other else other
```

- or any other combination did not work for me.

Note that I am also unable to define `__bool__(self)` since it's return value isn't `True` nor `False` and returning `NotImplemented` is not allowed.

So my question: **is it possible to override the `or`, and `and` operators so that it might return something other than `True` or `False`?**

---

Edit: Thanks to [@CoryKramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458) and [@Martijn Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) comment below.

I was under the impression that `__or__` is for the logical `or` operator. It is not. It is for the bitwise `|` and in fact there is no way to override the logical `or` operator.

Comment: I'm puzzled by two questions: a) why do you think `(unknown or True) is True` should be `True`, and b) what does "did not work for me" mean exactly? What's the desired result?

Comment: For what it's worth, [PEP 335](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) proposed allowing overloadable boolean operators a while ago, but it was rejected.

Comment: No, you can't override the boolean logical operators. They evaluate the second argument lazily, and any hook implementation would have to forgo that feature.

Comment: @timgeb: (a) The motivation of such an `Unknown` class is to propagate values in a system when not all of them are known, and to try and limit that unknown state. In the case of `or` operation, since one operator is `True` the result should also be true no matter what the unknown should turn out to be. (b) "Did not work for me" means that the asserts above did not pass.

Comment: "In the case of or operation, since one operator is True the result should also be true no matter what the unknown should turn out to be" <- In your first assert, Python does not even look at `True`. `bool(unknown)` is `True` so the `or` expression evaluates to `unknown`. E.g. `(unknown or True) is unknown` -> `True`.

Answer (score -1):

Why not? Did you try? Seems to work just fine...

```
class Unknown:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self

unknown = Unknown()
assert (unknown or unknown) is unknown
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. `__or__` is only called for the **bitwise** `|` operator.

Comment: Your `assert`  asserts the default behaviour, not the behaviour OP asks for.